# Based on this graph, should I use a Box-Cox transformation?

Tags: time-series, data-transformation

Graph of difference data and residuals are below [image]d data
[image]The graph displays monthly US oil production.

[image]

Comment: well, but then can you show us a plot of the differenced series, and maybe a plot of the residuals from some simple model? Maybe some of these posts can help:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=time+series+box-cox

Comment: The residuals -- from what model? -- look approximately symmetric but with fatter tails than a normal. No Box-Cox transformation will obviously improve on that. Does the model include a term for seasonality?

Comment: @NickCox Yes it does include a seasonal term